# Creating Data set for Change Point Detection Output performed over time series data

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series

I have computed change point detection using `cpt.mean` and output of this syntax gives `constant mean` and respective position across times series. So here i am trying to create a data set for the same for below reproducible Example.

```
s <- data.frame(Tag = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2),row = c(1,12,22,1,7,9,16),constant_mean=c(-0.12,1.55,0,0.35,1.6,0.86,0))
```

So here as one can observe there are three column `Tag`,`row`&`constant_mean`

So lets take example for only for `Tag=1` for this `Maximum rows would be 22` such that `row 1 to row 12` the constant mean would be -0.12. and then `row13 to row22` the constant mean would be 1.55. `and similarly for Tag=2 this would be a group by method`.As similar in image as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using data.table

```
library(data.table)
res <-
  setDT(s)[, 
          .SD[c(1L, rep(1L : (.N - 1L), diff(row)))],
          by = Tag
         ][, row := .I] # don't think this is needed

res
#     Tag row constant_mean
#  1:   1   1         -0.12
#  2:   1   2         -0.12
#  3:   1   3         -0.12
#  4:   1   4         -0.12
#  5:   1   5         -0.12
#  6:   1   6         -0.12
#  7:   1   7         -0.12
#  8:   1   8         -0.12
#  9:   1   9         -0.12
# 10:   1  10         -0.12
# 11:   1  11         -0.12
# 12:   1  12         -0.12
# 13:   1  13          1.55
# 14:   1  14          1.55
# 15:   1  15          1.55
# 16:   1  16          1.55
# 17:   1  17          1.55
# 18:   1  18          1.55
# 19:   1  19          1.55
# 20:   1  20          1.55
# 21:   1  21          1.55
# 22:   1  22          1.55
# 23:   2  23          0.35
# 24:   2  24          0.35
# 25:   2  25          0.35
# 26:   2  26          0.35
# 27:   2  27          0.35
# 28:   2  28          0.35
# 29:   2  29          0.35
# 30:   2  30          1.60
# 31:   2  31          1.60
# 32:   2  32          0.86
# 33:   2  33          0.86
# 34:   2  34          0.86
# 35:   2  35          0.86
# 36:   2  36          0.86
# 37:   2  37          0.86
# 38:   2  38          0.86
```

This basically expends the rows per Tag by the diff in `row`. I'm adding a `1` at the beginning because `row` in each group begins from `1` and hence the diff is always short by one. 
Regarding `row`, I wasn't sure if you just want the overall row number (which is redundant IMO) or you want it by `Tag`. if the later is the case, then this would be something like `[, row := as.numeric(seq_len(.N)), by = Tag]`

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong .`SD` means a Operation on every unique group by element.And what is `1L` ? . it would be very helpful if little bit , i usually use dplyr it was difficult with that. thank you very much.

Comment: `.SD` means "**S**ub **D**ata"- which basically means you want to operate over the whole data by group. `1L` means that I want `1` to be an `integer` rather than `numeric`. This is just a habit of mine for efficiency reasons. You don't really need the `L` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

A more general solution is using the `mcp` package to simulate change point data. Time series often involve autocorrelation, so let's include that in the mix.

```r
library(mcp)
empty = mcp(model, sample = FALSE, par_x = "x")

df = data.frame(x = 1:200)
df$y = empty$simulate(
  df$x, 
  cp_1 = 90,  # where the change point occurs
  int_1 = -0.12,  # intercept of segment 1
  int_2 = 1.66,  # intercept of segment 2
  ar1_1 = 0.6,  # autoregressive strength
  sigma_1 = 0.5)  # standard deviations of the residuals (innovations)
```

Let's go ahead and use `mcp` to see if we can recover these parameters, also to get the default plot visualizing the data:

```r
fit = mcp(model, df, par_x = "x")
plot(fit)
```

[image]

See the parameter estimates:

```r
summary(fit)

Family: gaussian(link = 'identity')
Iterations: 9000 from 3 chains.
Segments:
  1: y ~ 1 + ar(1)
  2: y ~ 1 ~ 1

Population-level parameters:
    name match   sim  mean lower upper Rhat n.eff
   ar1_1    OK  0.60  0.61  0.49  0.75    1   164
    cp_1       90.00 90.04 89.01 89.99    1    15
   int_1       -0.12 -0.45 -0.75 -0.18    1   391
   int_2    OK  1.66  1.48  1.22  1.73    1  1178
 sigma_1    OK  0.50  0.50  0.45  0.55    1   681
```

[This site](https://lindeloev.github.io/mcp/articles/arma.html) contains more information about modeling time series data with `mcp`. Disclosure: I am the developer of `mcp`.